# How to make an image selection with ejs and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am using node, express, moongoDB, and EJS to make a blog site with a custom post management system. That all works well, but I am now trying to use Cloudinary uploaded images from my mongoDB to add multiple images to posts on an upload/edit page. In theory it works very simply, as I just need to append image IDs or URLs to a chosen post document.But selecting which post, and which images on one page is giving me headaches.
I'm struggling to use front-end JS and EJS in harmony with this as the selection needs to be made on the front end and posted to the back-end through the html form, I assume with an array that includes my image selections.
My code makes an array called 'imageSelection' to store the images picked by the user with JS, and then it attempts to JSON stringify and POST the array to the server for processing.

I was able to save the images in an array with JS, and to use a foreach to cycle through the ones from my database to display the options with EJS. I can then only figure out how to POST static data but that doesn't work in the way I need it to since I want to post the image selection array after stringifying it. I seem to be unable to use plain JS to stringify and post the data I store in my array in vanilla JS because I need to call a function and then insert the data into the submitted value. I'm not sure this is the only problem with my code here though.

I have a preview of the chosen images, which should display but I can't use my former code because it works with EJS, and it needs to work with plain JS to access my 'imageSelection' array.

```
    <form action="/post-add-imgs" method="post">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a Post
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu  hover_img">
      <%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
        <li><a href="#"><%=post.title%></a></li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
    </div>

  <div class="uploads-gallery">
    <%  images.forEach(function(image){ %>
      <a href="#" onclick=" addImage(<%=image.url%>); "><img src="<%=image.url%>" alt="preview image" 
  height="100" /></a>
      <% }); %>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name=" imageSelection " value="json.stringify(imageSelection);">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Add image choice</button>
  </form>
```

Is there a way to use ejs to display the selected images, and then to post them on after a json.stringify?
Will I need to use ajax to accomplish this?

Thanks for all help, and wise words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but let's see if I can help with what I think I know. I think you need to be able to select some images that are rendered via an .ejs file, store the image url's in an array via client-side JS, then send that array in a POST request to an Express server.

Here's how I would do that, using your code as a basis:

**Client Side**

I created an .ejs file that rendered some images that my Express server sent across in an 'images' local variable:

```
<div id="image-container">
  <% images.forEach((image) => { %>
     <a href="#"><img src="<%= image.url %>"></a>
  <% }) %>
</div>

<button id="add-image-button">Add Image Choice</button>
```

Then, I have a .js file that adds images that are clicked to an 'imageSelection' array using an event listener on the `<div>` that wraps the images:

```
const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
const imageSelection = [];

imageContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!imageSelection.includes(e.target.src)) {
    imageSelection.push(e.target.src);
  }
});
```

And finally, when the user clicks the 'Add Image Choice' button, the images in the 'imageSelection' array are sent via a fetch request to the endpoint 'http://localhost:3001/post-images'. The addImageButton has an eventListener attached to it that listens for the 'click' event, so you don't need a `<form>` element:

```
const addImageButton = document.getElementById('add-image-button');

addImageButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/post-images';
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(imageSelection)
  });
  const myJson = await response.json();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```

**Server-Side**

On the Express side, I have a route handler setup for the POST /post-images request that simply sends back the POST-ed data to the requester:

```
router.post('/post-images', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

So, for your purposes, this pattern allows the user to select images and then click a button and the url's of those images are sent to the server. If that's not what you're looking for, clarify and I will try and help.

It's currently Saturday, 11-16-2019 at 9:34 pm GMT as I'm editing this, and I'm leaving the house and won't be able to assist for another 20 hours or so, so don't expect a response before 5:30 pm GMT on Sunday, 11-17-2019.

I pushed my code up to a git repo [here](https://github.com/Dayun123/image-selection), just follow the instructions in the README and you should be able to test it out on your machine. The files you want to check out for this example specifically are:

- views/index.ejs
- public/javascripts/main.js
- routes/index.js

Here's an image of the front-end, with the response logged after selecting the first two images:

[image]

Comment: That is incredibly helpful, and I find you understand my problem well. This may be plenty for me to complete my solution.

The single element I need to add now is a post selector so I can pick which blog post to add my image selection to.
I plan to do this in the POST route by taking the parsed image array, and appending it onto the mongo document for the post I select on the front end.

You have been more than helpful, I sincerely appreciate you.

Comment: I've got your code implemented in my site, and it works brilliantly except for posting. I'm not too sure why, but here are the errors on the page:  


`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
  :3000/post-images:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 
  of 404 (Not Found)
  main.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at 
  position 0`

Comment: @JacobSiler that seems like you are trying to read HTML as JSON. See if this article helps: https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Comment: @JacobSiler actually if the server is responding with a 404 it may mean that you are sending the fetch request to a route that doesn't exist. What URL are you sending the POST request to? My example was setup for my specific server at the route POST /post-images with the url http://localhost:3001/post-images. If you don't have a route-handler for that, then you would get this error for sure. Notice that in the fetch request I have a url variable, that should point to YOUR endpoint where the POST requests should go. From your example, that was '/post-add-imgs'.

Comment: Here's my current code:
`const url = "http://localhost:3000/post-images";`

And my attempt to handle the route:
`//When someone picks images.
router.post("/post-images", (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.body);
  console.log("Post route working!");
});`
The strange thing is that it logs that the route is working properly, but no data in the bash console. It also gives the error in the browser console. 
But. I can verify that it is pointing to the js file, but it shows up with the uploads.ejs content in sources.

Comment: in my app.js I require express and make an instance of it called 'app' I haven't used `express.Router` before so I just required it and named it router to make your code work, but I just changed it to`app.post"/post-images", ...` instead and now I can verify that the post route is working but I still get a 404 error code, and an unexpected syntax error in the console.

Comment: Well, I have cleaned up my code a bit and there aren't any errors now, but I now only receive an empty set of curly braces again. I verified that imageSelection has two images in the array before clicking the add images button.

Comment: Further update:
I just needed to include `app.use(express.json());` to my node app.js and it solved all remaining errors! :D Thanks so much for your kind help in solving my issues and getting this done. Can't thank you enough @Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: I am now struggling to append my images to my chosen Mongoose post documents. Should I post a completely new question for this?

Comment: My current code:
`app.post("/post-images", (req, res) => {
  //const post=req
  const postImages = req.body;
  const postID = postImages.shift();
  //res.json(postImages);
  console.log(postID);
  Post.update(
    { _id: postID },
    { $push: { imageUrls: [{ postImages }] } },
    { upsert: true },
    function(err, foundPost) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(foundPost);
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});`

Comment: The post schema: `const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,
  imageUrls: [{ type: String }]
};

const Post = new mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);`

And some simple changes to main.js to add the current post ID to update to the beginning of `imageSelection` so I can identify what post to add the images to in the post route.
`addImageButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/post-images";
  if (postValue !== "undefined") {
    // Unshift post selection to the imageSelection array
    imageSelection.unshift(postValue);`

Comment: Above that in the main.js I added this to get data from a "posts selector" dropdown on my EJS page on the frontend. `//post selection logic
$("#post-dropdown").on("change", function() {
  postValue = $(this).val();
});`

Here is that EJS post dropdown:   `<!-- The post selection logic -->
<hr>

    <h1>Select a post to add images to:</h1>
    <select id="post-dropdown" name="post">
      <%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
        <option value="<%=post.id%>"> <%=post.title%> </option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>

<hr>`

Comment: @JacobSiler Yeah, post a new question for sure. Make sure you explain clearly what you are trying to do. Show what the expected result is, what your current result is, and document a little about what you've tried to do to fix the issue. Include only relevant details to the problem at hand, and only the code that is the problem.

Comment: I will absolutely. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I asked the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978242/how-can-i-get-mongoose-to-push-an-array-of-urls-to-an-array-subdocument